# Valor por defecto cuando no existe el ID en la DB (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

en palabras simples tengo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT c.id FROM customers AS c WHERE c.id IN (10, 20 , 30, 40)
```

Lo cual retorna:

```
10
30
```

Pero mi objetivo es que retorne

```
10
'false'
30
'false'
```

En el mismo orden especificado por IN.

Es posible sin tener que iterar por cada valor del id?
muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Eso que buscas no es una salida standar de ninguna base de datos, por lo menos con sql solo. por ahi si con un proceso.. ahora si esto es para mostrar en un front end... el que deberia arreglarlo es el front end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sentencia select NO funciona de esa manera. Esta simplemente devolverá los registros que cumplan con las condiciones.

El operador `in` es *azucar sintáctica* para una sentencia como esta:

```
SELECT c.id 
  FROM customers AS c 
 WHERE c.id = 10
    or c.id = 20 
    or c.id = 30
    or c.id = 40
```

De hecho, muchos motores *traducen* sentencias con el operador `in` a sentencias con una serie de `or` tal como he mostrado.

Puedes lograr lo que buscas valiéndote de un `CTE` que forme una tabla *al vuelo* con los valores que te interesan, por ejemplo:

```
with 
Buscados as (
  select 10 as id
  union all select 20   
  union all select 30
  union all select 40
)
select b.id, c.id, case when c.id is null then 'false' else 'true' end
  from customers as c
       right join Buscados as b on b.id = c.id
 order by b.id
```

Que devolvería:

```
10    10     'true'
20    null   'false'
30    30     'true'
40    null   'false'
```

los registros que tienen `null` en la segunda columna son los que no existen.

Comment: Genial!, funciona, solo tengo un inconveniente, mi tabla customers tiene 120millones de rows, entonces hacer un right join demora un monton, pero es lo mejor que tengo hasta ahora.

Comment: Suponiendo que la lista que buscas no es tan grande, y que buscas por la llave primaria o un campo que tiene un índice, el rendimiento debiera ser bueno. Evalúa el plan, asegúrate que la búsqueda se basa en la lista de valores y no en un full table/index scan. Puedes adaptar el ejemplo para usar una tabla adicional que esté también indexada, si hiciera falta.

Comment: Hice una tabla temporal e inserté los valores que quiero buscar allí como clave primaria, usando tu sugerencia y reemplazando el with() con esta tabla temporal pude obtener lo que quería de forma muy rápida. Muchas gracias!